# CFC not found with paypal sdk

Tags: paypal, coldfusion, application.cfc

I am using a colfusion paypal SDK for direct payments, the link is here:
https://github.com/paypal/nvp-coldfusion-sdk

I have pasted the application.cfc file below.  My issue is that every time I go to the samples --> dodirectpayment.cfm and submit the test form, It states "Error: Could not find the ColdFusion component or interface CallerService."  I think this has to do with referencing the callerservice.cfc file, but can't figure out what is going wrong.  Any help is much appreciated. The application.cfc is here.

```
<cfscript>
/**
@dateCreated "July 18, 2011"
@hint "You implement methods in Application.cfc to handle ColdFusion application events and set variables in the CFC to configure application characteristics."
*/


component output="false" {

    /* **************************** APPLICATION VARIABLES **************************** */
    THIS.name = "NVPSample";
    THIS.applicationTimeout = createTimeSpan(0, 2, 0, 0);


    customtagpaths = "{#getDirectoryFromPath(ExpandPath('../lib/'))#,#getDirectoryFromPath(ExpandPath('../lib/services/'))#}";

    THIS.customTagPaths = customtagpaths; 

    THIS.serverSideFormValidation = true;
    THIS.sessionManagement = true;
    THIS.sessionTimeout = createTimeSpan(0, 0, 30, 0);

    THIS.setClientCookies = true;
    THIS.setDomainCookies = false;

    THIS.scriptProtect = true;
    THIS.secureJSON = false;
    THIS.secureJSONPrefix = "";


    THIS.enablerobustexception = true;


/* **************************** APPLICATION METHODS **************************** */

    public void function onApplicationEnd(struct ApplicationScope=structNew()) {

        return;
    }


    public boolean function onApplicationStart() {

        return true;
    }

    public void function onCFCRequest(required string cfcname, required string method, required string args) {

        return;
    }


    public void function onRequestEnd() {

        return;
    }


    public boolean function onRequestStart(required string TargetPage) {

        request.serverURL = "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp";

        /* SUBJECT to be uncommented for UNIPAY all the other credentials like API username,
              password,signature can be commented for UNIPAY
              To enable Payments for Third Party Email whcih will be passed along with Partner's 3token credentials
              uncomment both subject and 3 token credentials.
       */


        request.SUBJECT="sales-facilitator@totalsportsadvantage.com"; 

        APIuserName = "sales-facilitator_api1.totalsportsadvantage.com";
        APIPassword = "1387466817";
        APISignature = "An5ns1Kso7MWUdW4ErQKJJJ4qi4-AMJWATXVSChE1ExjnH8FyoZD8U5Q";

        /*
         request.SUBJECT="clip_1309031681_biz@paypal.com"; 

        APIuserName = "clip_1309031681_biz_api1.paypal.com";
        APIPassword = "1309031732";
        APISignature = "AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31An2lFbilAjH412uQjiC0OEJh45pL";
        */

        //condition to check if it is UNIPAY 
        if (isdefined("SUBJECT") && (isdefined("APIuserName") eq "false" && isdefined("APIPassword") eq "false" && isdefined("APISignature") eq "false") )
        {
            request.UNIPAYSUBJECT="#SUBJECT#"; 
            request.USER = "";
            request.PWD = "";
            request.SIGNATURE = "";
        }



        //condition to check if it is Payments for Third Party Email
        if (isdefined("SUBJECT") && isdefined("APIuserName") && isdefined("APIPassword") && isdefined("APISignature"))
        {
            request.UNIPAYSUBJECT="#SUBJECT#"; 
            request.USER = "#APIuserName#";
            request.PWD = "#APIPassword#";
            request.SIGNATURE = "#APISignature#";
        }


        //condition to check if it is 3 token credentials 
        if (isdefined("SUBJECT") eq "false" && isdefined("APIuserName") && isdefined("APIPassword") && isdefined("APISignature") )
        {
            request.UNIPAYSUBJECT=""; 
            request.USER = "#APIuserName#";
            request.PWD = "#APIPassword#";
            request.SIGNATURE = "#APISignature#";
        }


        request.PayPalURL = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=";
        request.version = "65.1";

        /*
        By default the API requests doesn't go through proxy. To route the requests through a proxy server
            set "useProxy" value as "true" and set values for proxyName and proxyPort. Set proxyName with
        the Host Name or the IP address of the proxy server. proxyPort should be a valid port number.
        eg: 
        useProxy = "true";
        proxyName = "127.0.0.1";
        proxyPort = "8081";
        */

        request.useProxy = "false";
        request.proxyName = "";
        request.proxyPort = "";

        return true;
    }


    public void function onSessionEnd(required struct SessionScope, struct ApplicationScope=structNew()) {

        return;
    }


    public void function onSessionStart() {

        return;
    }

}
</cfscript>
```

Comment: When I did a search for callerservice.cfc in your code sample, I couldn't find it either.

Comment: It is a custom tag in the /lib/services folder of the SDK I linked to.

Comment: What have you done by way or troubleshooting?

Comment: Does `getDirectoryFromPath(ExpandPath('../lib/services/'))` resolve to the actual location of those files from the perspective of the file you're browsing to?

Comment: the getDirectoryFromPath did refer to an actual location of those files, but for some reason the application wasn't finding them in that location.  The ultimate solution was to copy the files into the same folder as the application.cfc file and things are working as expected.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

the getDirectoryFromPath did refer to an actual location of those files, but for some reason the application wasn't finding them in that location. The ultimate solution was to copy the files into the same folder as the application.cfc file and things are working as expected. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's good that you got it working, but I don't think that's much of a "solution". You ought to have worked through why "but for some reason [etc]". The reason will be "your apps got a problem with it somewhere" which you really ought to discover and fix.